# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class using serial columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, pojo

I have created two tables namely abc and def, I have generated pojo classes for both using annotations, but when I try to execute the project I am getting maaping exception. can anyone tell me how to write pojo for a table with serial nuber as primary key and foreign key(oneToMany).

```
CREATE TABLE abc  
(  
abc_id serial NOT NULL,  
abc_name character varying(30),    
CONSTRAINT abc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (abc_id)  
)  
WITH (  
OIDS=FALSE  
);  
ALTER TABLE abc  
OWNER TO postgres;  


CREATE TABLE def
(
def_id serial NOT NULL,
abc_id bigint NOT NULL,  
CONSTRAINT def_pkey PRIMARY KEY (def_id),
CONSTRAINT def_fkey FOREIGN KEY (abc_id)
REFERENCES abc (abc_id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE def
OWNER TO postgres;
```

and the classes, Abc

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "abc")  
public class Abc implements Serializable {  

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "def_id")
      private BigInteger def_id;

      @Column(name = "abc_name")
      public String abc_name;

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "abc_id")
    List<Def> list;
 }
```

and Def

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "def")
public class Def implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "def_id")
      private BigInteger def_id;

      @Column(name = "abc_id")
  public BigInteger abc_id;

 }
```

Comment: can you share your entities please?

Comment: Dear @YCF_L, I have added my entities, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it all wrong. Check this [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_relationship_and_inverse_ManyToOne_annotations)

You use annotation **@JoinColumn** in *DEF* class like that

```
(....)
@JoinColumn("abc_id")
public BigInteger abc_id_test;
```

And on the *ABC* you should use **mappedBy** property

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="abc_id_test")
private List<Def> list;
```

More information you can find in wiki article which I included. Try to rewrite this mapping : )

Comment: Errm no. "mappedBy", when specified, should point to a field/property in the related class of the type of this side ("Abc" in this case), when you want the relation to be BIDIRECTIONAL. You don't use "BigInteger" for that.